# How can I retrieve the list of permissions assigned to a Sight (Dashboard)?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to retrieve the groups/users that have access to view a particular Sight (Dashboard) in Smartsheet.  I'm using the Java API from Smartsheet but I also don't see any method that associates the groups to what they have access from either end (Sight or Group).  Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get that information?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that information by using the [List Sight Shares](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-sight-shares) operation.

As the documentation describes, the following code uses the Java SDK to retrieve sharing information for the specified Sight (without specifying pagination info):

```
smartsheet.sightResources().shareResources().listShares(
  6327127650920324,    // long sightId
  null,    // PaginationParameters
  true    // includeWorkspaceShares
);
```

This operation returns an `IndexResult` object that contains an array of `Share` objects -- one for each User or Group that has access to the specified Sight.

Comment: Thanks very much, Kim.  That worked!  Didn't think to look at 'shares' for it.  :)

Comment: Happy I could help!